# Possible to use LayerGroup for GeoJSON Polygons, MultiLineStrings and LineStrings?

Tags: javascript, dc.leaflet.js

In the leaflet.js documentation an example with layers of markers is documented. I would like to create a layer of polygons in GeoJSON format. Is this possible?

I've defined a variable for each GeoJSON polygon, called route1, route2 etc. My .js file looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [55.676098, 12.568337],
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

//============
//Create layer
//============

var Southroutes = new L.layerGroup([route1, route2, route3, route4, route5]);

L.geoJSON(Southroutes).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat geojson objects before add to map.

```
var features = [];
[route1, route2, route3].forEach(function(route){
  features = features.concat(route.features);
})

var Southroutes = L.geoJSON({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": features
}).addTo(map);
```

Or, just use leaflet.js geojson [addData](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson-adddata)

```
var Southroutes = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
[route1, route2, route3].forEach(function(route){
  Southroutes.addData(route);
})
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pp9dtf0u/))